# header redirect on php form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

I'm new to PHP and just needed it for this form. I had it working earlier but now it's deciding not to work. Any help is much appreciated.

PHP Section with header going to page in same directory

```
<!-- PHP Form E-mailer -->

        <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'Very Local';
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // BUSINESS EMAIL ADDRESS
        $subject = 'Message from Very Local';

        $body ="From: $name\n Number: $phone\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['phone'] || !filter_var($_POST['phone'])) {
            $errphone = 'Please enter a valid phone number';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errPhone && !$errMessage) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
         header("Location: success.html");
    } else {
        header("Location: fail.html");
    }
}
    }
?>
```

and my HTML within bootstrap.

```
<!-- FORM SECTION -->

<div id="callcontain" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">



                <form id="contact-form" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">


                                <!-- Form Name -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required="required" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Name -->

                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6">


                                <!-- Form Number -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone Number <small>*</small></label>
                                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" required="required" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPhone</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Number -->

                            </div>

                        </div>  <!-- END ROW 1 FORM -->



                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">


                                <!-- Form Message -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="message"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
                                    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- END Form Message -->


                            </div>


                            <!-- Form Submit -->

                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success btn-send">
                            </div>

                            <!-- END Form Submit -->


                        </div>


                        <!-- Form Required -->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <p class="text-muted small">* These fields are required.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <?php echo $result; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </form> <!-- END FORM -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>  <!-- END FORM SECTION -->
```

Form sends fine but re-direct isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have output before the `header`, that's the problem. Remove everything before `<?php`!

Comment: are you sure this if (!$errName && !$errPhone && !$errMessage)  is true?

Comment: @jeff You are totally right. That's what I added. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an **exit;** after the header redirect.

Comment: Thank you mate. I added that too as when i googled people said it was important. the main problem was the comment before the code, through everything off.